# API python jira

Tags: python, rest, jira-rest-api, python-jira

i want to change the status of an jira test plan ,
inside this test plan there is 10 tests that are associated to test execution 'RO-6665'
i want to update the status of those test from 'TODO' to 'PASS'

BUT I GOT THIS :
Failed to retrieve issue details. Status code 401
even i checked all tokens and acces :

here is my code:

```
import os
from jira import JIRA
import requests
import json


# Define your Jira server URL, username, and API token
JIRA_SERVER = 'example tokens'
JIRA_USER = 'example tokens'
JIRA_API_TOKEN = 'example tokens'

# Define the Jira issue key for the test plan and execution
test_plan_key = 'RO-6666'
execution_key = 'RO-6665'

# Define the new status to set (e.g., 'PASS')
new_status = 'PASS'

# Set the Jira API endpoints for issue retrieval and transition
issue_url = f"{JIRA_SERVER}/rest/api/2/issue/{execution_key}"
transitions_url = f"{issue_url}/transitions"

# Define Jira options with headers for authentication and content type
jira_options = {
    'server': JIRA_SERVER,
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}

# Authenticate using basic auth (username and API token)
auth = (JIRA_USER, JIRA_API_TOKEN)

# Step 1: Get the issue details
response = requests.get(issue_url, headers=jira_options['headers'], auth=auth)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve issue details. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    exit()

issue_data = response.json()
current_status = issue_data["fields"]["status"]["name"]

# Check if the current status is 'TODO'
if current_status != 'TODO':
    print(f"Test execution {execution_key} is not in 'TODO' status. Current status: {current_status}")
else:
    # Step 2: Get available transitions for the issue
    response = requests.get(transitions_url, headers=jira_options['headers'], auth=auth)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve available transitions. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        exit()

    transitions_data = response.json()

    # Find the transition ID for the 'PASS' status
    for transition in transitions_data["transitions"]:
        if transition["to"]["name"] == new_status:
            transition_id = transition["id"]
            break
    else:
        print(f"Transition to '{new_status}' status not found.")
        exit()

    # Step 3: Perform the transition to update the status
    transition_data = {"transition": {"id": transition_id}}
    response = requests.post(transitions_url, headers=jira_options['headers'], json=transition_data, auth=auth)

    if response.status_code == 204:
        print(f"Test execution {execution_key} status updated to '{new_status}'.")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to update status. Status code: {response.status_code}")
```

Comment: Why the Java tag in a Python question?

Comment: it's a mistake, sorry

Comment: Are you a 100% sure your JIRA server, user and token are correct? From JIRA: "A 401 error will occur if the credentials being passed to Jira Server in the API call's headers aren't valid, or if the user doesn't have permission to use the endpoint being called."

Comment: If your are using JIRA library instead of using post requests, you can connect with:

options = {
 'server': server
}

jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=(user,apikey))

Then you can look for an issue with:

issue = jira.issue('ISSUE_KEY')

Comment: Are you using your user's mail as JIRA_USER?